# How can I recover Endpoint Encryption bootloader?

Tags: hard-drive, grub2, encrypted-partition

I have a bit of a problem. I have a Win 7 partition encrypted with Mcafee Endpoint Encryption. I used to boot with MEE, but GRUB replaced that bootloader. I made the huge mistake of not making a backup of the mbr :(. Now I can load Ubuntu, but when I try to load the Win7 partition the following message is shown: "Missing Operating System..."

Is there any way to recover my encrypted partition data(I have the username and password)? Or is there a way to recover the MEE bootloader?

Comment: Do you have a Wintech Cd?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I don't have access to a windows system to create the boot cd :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some checking for you in relation to this and it looks like bad news to be honest. 
Without access to the Wintech CD (The MEE recovery software) or the Safetech FD (Pre version 5) it is almost and I say almost impossible to recover the files.

I don't know if you can download an ISO of the Wintech Cd and use your .SDB file (Assuming you created one when you set-up the encryption.

There are companies that specialise in recovering data from Hard drives and this sort of error and I know my company deal with this kind of issue on a much lesser scale so it may be worth thinking about that option however as you have now installed Ubuntu I am daring to make the assumption losing this HDD for a while is not an option.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to get a recovery ISO built by a support tech who had access to my machine's encryption XML file.  Third item you need is McAfee's daily recovery code.  After fully decrypting the Win7 partition, I was able to boot without issue.

My scenario I had was a dual boot Xubuntu / Win7 setup.  GRUB gave access to either OS flawlessly.  Afterwards, encrypted the Win7 partition using McAfee's WDE via my company's management server (ePO).

A month after encrypting, I received a GRUB update and this caused an issue with the Windows loader.  When I selected Win7 it gave me the same error.

Comment: Its best to keep a backup of the MBR on another machine when using drive encryption like that.   See here for info on how to make the backup: https://superuser.com/a/936073/253747